# how to set up the listener for SimpleAdapter

Tags: android

I have created a list/table sorts with the following code.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btTaken);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String Date;
    //list.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
 //   list.setOnItemClickListener(ListItemClick);
    //  cb.setVisibility();
    Date=AttendanceDao.Dates()[0];
    for(i=0;i<AttendanceDao.Dates().length;i++)
    {

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Date", AttendanceDao.Dates()[i]);
    //map.put("StudentName",Data.Sname()[i]);

    mylist.add(map);
    }

    // ...
    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.att_date_list,
            AttendanceDao.Datemap(), new int[] {R.id.Sid});

    list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

This part of the code

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {//this guy is not working!
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent openActivity = new Intent("net.vrixx.activities.ATTENDANCELISTACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openActivity);

        }
```

is supposed to listen to the item clicked on my list. But it doesnt work Can anyone figure out why? thanks!

Comment: It extends from a Activity only Anders..
I have two xml layouts for this..one for general layout,where mention list and the other xml I describe the views that has to be in the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
    list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```